# NSCollectionView size is wrong

Tags: macos, nscollectionview

NSCollectionView show a wrong size for the items when using the method " transition(from:  to: options: completionHandler:)" to trans to the NSCollectionView's controller. If you change the window size ,it will be recover to right size. I don't know how to do now, anyone can help me?

Comment: Having same problem here, have you found the solution yet?

Comment: I have not found a perfect solution, just resized the window manually. I still looking forward a better solution.